Why is my target showing up with a non-zero centered velocity? I captured this data using the IWR6843A0P using a stationary corner reflector
I need help understanding what I should do to determine why my target is showing up in my Range doppler map with a non-zero centered velocity when I captured my measurement using a stationary corner reflector?
This is how I calculate and display the velocity axis:
% Use the imagesc function to plot the output of 2DFFT and to show axis in both
% dimensions
idle_time = 100*1e-6;
velocity_res = radar.Lambda_m/(2*radar.num_chirps); % number of chirps in a frame     
improves velocity resolution
prf = 1 / (radar.chirp_dur_secs + idle_time);
unambig_max_vel = (radar.Lambda_m / 4) * prf;
velocity_axis = linspace(-unambig_max_vel, unambig_max_vel,num_rows);

figure(2)
imagesc(range_axis,velocity_axis,fftshift(RDM,2));
title( 'RDM From 2D FFT');
ylabel('Velocity (m/s)');
xlabel('Range (m)');
colorbar;
axis xy
colormap jet
clim([85 120])

Here is a picture of my target


What is idle time? What is that accounting for?

I think you need to include more information. For instance, how is RDM computed?
